# Display image above another linked image on mouseover using CSS only

Tags: css, mouseover

I want image big.png to be displayed on `mouseover` above the linked image.
And after it is displayed it can be clicked to be send to specified link.

No javascript is required. Only CSS.

I am not getting the position of the `mouseover` image correct...

```
<style>

.brands-listing{
    width:100%;
    padding:10%;
    list-style:none;
}

.brands-listing li{
    width:25%;
    display:inline;
    margin-right:50px;
}

div {
    display: none;

}

a:hover > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top:-100px;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="brands-listing">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="hover-image" alt="Flying Saucer" src="1.png" width="230" height="60">
          <div>
            <img alt="Flying Saucer" src="big1.png" width="280" height="120">
          </div>
        </a>
    </li>


    <li href="#">
        <a>
         <img class="hover-image" alt="Open House" src="2.jpg" width="230" height="60">
         <div>
          <img alt="Open House" src="big2.png" width="280" height="120">
         </div>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="hover-image" alt="Flying Saucer" src="3.png" width="230" height="60">
           <div>
             <img alt="Flying Saucer" src="big3.png" width="280" height="120">
           </div>
        </a>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img class="hover-image" alt="Open House" src="4.png" width="230" height="60">
          <div>
            <img alt="Open House" src="big4.png" width="280" height="120">
          </div>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: did u fix the double quation in the: src="big4.png

Comment: Use a title that sums up your problem rather than a generic "please help", that way you are more likely to get constructive advice.